# Как правильно настроить работу групп захвата в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение, состоящее из трех групп.
1 группа - набор команд (обязательно надо вводить)
2 группа - номер события (необязательно вводить)
3 группа - событие (необязательно вводить).
Вот мое выражение:

```
(\s*^add|list|edit\b)(\s+\d*)(\s*.*).
```

Ввод первой группы (команда) не определяется, пока не поставлю пробел в конце после ввода, а если ввести пробел, то первая группа определяется, НО возникает проблема при компиляции: `NumberFormatException: For input string: " 4"`.
Я так понимаю, это из-за пробела?

Comment: `(\s*^add|list|edit\b)(\s+\d*)(\s*.*)` \s* перед символом начала строки использовать на мой взгляд бессмысленно, на всю группу можно устанавливать квантификатор отдельно, т.е. примерно можно написать так: `(^add|list|edit\b)(?:(?:\s+)(\d+))?(?:\s*(.*))?` исключая из группы захвата пробельные символы. Ошибка возникает вероятнее всего при преобразовании.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишу ответом:
Предложенный вами вариант: `(\s*^add|list|edit\b)(\s+\d*)(\s*.*)`

1. Указан `\s` - может произойти захват новой строки, нарушив при этом цепочку значений, в случае если в строке к примеру не указан комментарий
2. `\b` - установлено только для edit, остальные add, list, идут без границы слова, хотя по факту тут эта граница и не нужна, но если ее все же нужно использовать, то лучше вынести за пределы первой группы `(\s*^add|list|edit)\b`
3. Вторая группа `(\s+\d*)` описывает обязательное(квантификатор `+`) наличие одного и более пробелов и необязательного(квантификатор `*`) появления одной и более цифр. Правильнее было бы описать данный шаблон отделив пробельные символы от захвата, что бы не записывать получившиеся пробелы и сделать группу необязательной исходя из условия. Группы поддерживают квантификаторы, поэтому указать второй группе захвата квантификатор `?` и привести к виду `(?:[ \t]+(\d+))?`, где `?:` означает, что группа не подлежит групповому захвату, она нам нужна только для проверки, обязательное появление одного и более пробела или символа табуляции и обязательное появление одной и более цифры, которые мы ставим в группу захвата, это как раз и будет второй группой. Завершаем не захватываемую группу указанием квантификатора `?` означающего ноль или одно совпадение.
4. Третья группа в вашем примере захватывает ноль и более пробельных символов и далее ноль и более любых символов. Схема в данном случае будет аналогична второй группе
   `(?:[ \t]+(.+))?`

---

Итого, получаем примерно такой шаблон, в данном случае захват события будет всегда в третьей группе, а захват номера события во второй, даже если не указан номер события, а только событие.

```regex
^(add|list|edit)(?:[ \t]+(\d+))?(?:[ \t]+(.+))?$
```

Под данный шаблон будут подходить следующие строки:

```
add 12 Какой то комментарий
list 54345
edit Какой то комментарий
list
```

и подобные.

---

Если нужно будет исключить пробельные символы для захвата групп из строк типа:

```
list12комментарий какой-то
```

то в шаблоне следует поменять квантификаторы на захват пробельных символов:

```
^(add|list|edit)(?:[ \t]*(\d+))?(?:[ \t]*(.+))?
________________________^_______________^______
```

указав необязательное появление.

Попробовать и настроить шаблон регулярного выражения можно к примеру тут:
https://regex101.com/r/A9xHGx/1